# Building boost libraries for windows

Tags: boost

I'm trying to build boost static libs for mingw compiler on windows 8.1, using commands:

```
bootstrap.bat gcc
b2 toolset=gcc link=static --prefix=boost_mingw_530_static install
```

but getting as result `.a` files in `boost_mingw_530_static/lib` folder instead of `.lib`.
How to get `.lib` files?

Answer (score 1):

seems that `.lib` is not needed when using mingw, `.a` worked as well